# System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803 when validating Azure AD token

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, .net-core-3.0

I have a SPA client in Angular which logs into Azure AD successfully and generates a token which I then pass it to the .Net Core(3.0) API via `Authorization: Bearer ${token}`  I then try to validate the token with `[Authorize]` to check and then allow access to the REST Api calls, we are still using `"ver": "1.0"` and there is no nonce in the JWT header. I have the below code in ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                   options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidIssuer = options.Authority,
                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidAudience = "{myClientID}",
                       IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, parameter) => "https://sts.windows.net/{MyIssuer}/"
                   };
               });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy =
                     new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            });
```

When I run the project with locahost, it works fine, but I deploy the code to a server, I got the below error message :

```
Exception occurred while processing message.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The above message indicates that something is not allowing me to connect to the site to validate, are my parameters correct? I used jwt.io to check the token and it says the Signature is valid and on the body I get to see the values I expect for `"aud:","iss:" "amr":["pwd"]` etc. I am new to Azure AD and token validation, so please bear with me. Is there anything I am missing? Thank you

Comment: This error is caused by your API being unable to load the OpenID Discovery Document (/.well-known/openid-configuration) , do you have firewall setting on server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is caused by the app being unable to connect to the Azure AD metadata endpoint.
It needs to load configuration from there at the start, including public keys that the app can use to verify token signatures.

Either something is blocking the connection (like a firewall), or Azure AD is down (extremely unlikely).

Comment: Thank you juunas and @Nan-yu I guess I will have to figure that out with the infrastructure, are there any list of URLs that we have to whitelisted so firewall allows the links / configurations to show up? I can see this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls?tabs=public-cloud … should this suffice?, Also from the server from which I am trying to run the application has its firewall turned OFF, I checked it from "Windows Firewall with advanced security" tab and domain profile, private profile and public profile shows the "Windows firewall is off"

Comment: Thank you @juunas I will check it out with them tomorrow. Also, do I need to include [link ]https://login.microsoftonline.com/common for the CORS issue in the .net core code?

Comment: What CORS issue? Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: The exception I have posted was from the EventViewer, but when I saw the DevTools output `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://MyInternalAPIURL' from origin 'http:/MyClientURL'  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` The API is in .net Core 3.0 and Client is from Angular, so that's why I thought we may need to include the microsoft url in the .WithOrigins("allowedOrigins")

Comment: juunas and @nan-yu thank you for showing the correct direction. juunas thanks for validating and when we white listed the sites found in the URL in the above comments, it all worked magically, No CORS issue too. Thank you. I will mark it as an answer..